# LateInitializationError in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

To gove some background, I am trying to make a Settings page in my app, so I need to save the settings that the user chose. I am using Sliders, and I tried putting the updateSettings there, and even created a separated button where I inserted the same function...still doesn't work. I am using the is_first_run package as well, because when I pressed the settings button for the first time, the sliders should be at 50. I checked, I think that works, but I'll paste it here

```
bool _isFirstTimePressed = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkFirstTimePressed();
  }

  Future<void> _checkFirstTimePressed() async {
    final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final isFirstTimePressed = pref.getBool('is_first_time_pressed') ?? true;
    setState(() {
      _isFirstTimePressed = isFirstTimePressed;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _onButtonPressed() async {
    if (_isFirstTimePressed) {
      final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await pref.setBool('is_first_time_pressed', false);
      await pref.setDouble('keySoundVolume', 50);
      await pref.setDouble('keyMusicVolume', 50);
      setState(() {
        _isFirstTimePressed = false;
      });
      /*ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('This is the first time you pressed the button')),
      );
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('You have already pressed the button')),
      );*/
    }
  }
```

. In another class, another page of the app, I have 2 variables declared as :

```
late double soundVolume;
late double musicVolume;
```

I have the functions :

```
previousSettings() async {
    final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    soundVolume = pref.getDouble('keySoundVolume')!;
    musicVolume = pref.getDouble('keyMusicVolume')!;
  }

updateSettings() async {
    final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    pref.setDouble('keySoundVolume', soundVolume);
    pref.setDouble('keyMusicVolume', musicVolume);
  }
```

And this function is called in the initState. Recently found out that in initState I can not use async but I do not any other method. Can someone help me?

Comment: Check out [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

The "late" variable should be initial in the "onInit" function, if you read from SharedPreferences but it doesn't exist you should set a default value (e.g. soundVolume = pref.getDouble('keySoundVolume') ?? 50.0)